# How to join these tables with conditional joins

Tags: sql, recursion, join, sql-server-2012, conditional-statements

I saw some useful tips in the web, however I still have some questions.

[image]

This is the "main" part of the new site we are creating, it is based on SQL SERVER 2012, the "TAREAS" table is the main key table, which has a self join. I found a way to search for the "tree" of the table, TAREA=TASK, Spanish to English, so basically it is a task manager, on which one task could be part of a primary task, or be a secondary task which can have more "child" tasks. I did it using Common table expressions.

the thing here is on the ID_TipoTarea (TaskType) on TAREAS table, can be on one specific type of task, for example on the diagram there are 2 types availables (but there are and will be more), TipoTareaDesarrollo or TipoTareaEventoSalon, the ID_TipoTarea cant be on both tables, so if ID_TipoTarea=1 then I join on TIpoTareaDesarrollo, if ID_TipoTarea=2 then I join on TipoTareaEventoSalon and so on ID_TipoTarea=3 to another table, and there will be more types, can you help me out?.

how can it be achieved using this query (this is the query to get all the levels on the main table, but I need the conditional joins).

```
with tareasCTE (id_tarea,id_tareaorigen,id_tipoTarea,nivel)
as(
select *,0 as nivel from tareas t 
where id_tarea=@ID_Tarea 
union all
select t2.*,nivel+1 from tareasCTE t
inner join tareas t2
on t.id_tarea=t2.id_tareaOrigen
)
```

I get this output

```
ID_Tarea, ID_TareaORigen, Nivel, ID_TipoTarea

3 NULL 0 null (no join)

4 3 1 1 (join this one with TipoTareaDesarrollo)

5 3 1 1 (join this one with TipoTareaDesarrollo)

6 3 1 3 (join this one with AnotherTable)

7 4 2 2  (join this one with TipoTareaEventoSalon) 

8 4 2 2 (join this one with TipoTareaEventoSalon)

9 4 2 4 (join this one with AnotherTable2)

10 9 3 1 (join this one with TipoTareaDesarrollo) 

11 9 3 1 (join this one with TipoTareaDesarrollo)

12 9 3 null (no Join)

13 12 4 1 (join this one with TipoTareaDesarrollo)

14 12 4 2 (join this one with TipoTareaEventoSalon)

15 12 4 2 (join this one with TipoTareaEventoSalon)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine tables TipoTareaDesarrollo, TipoTareaEventoSalon, AnotherTable, AnotherTable2 into a single table using the UNION clause and package this in a second CTE as such:

```
WITH TipoAreasCTE as
(
SELECT * FROM TipoTareaDesarrollo
UNION 
SELECT * FROM TipoTareaEventoSalon
UNION 
SELECT * FROM AnotherTable
UNION 
SELECT * FROM AnotherTable2
)
```

You can then join tareasCTE to TipoAreasCTE.

Note that the different tables in the UNION must have the same number of columns with the same datatypes; if not you must use a SELECT list and perhaps CAST the datatypes to make them similar.

Comment: thats the thing the tables doesnt have the same type, they are different type of task, thats the deal, so i have no choice other than build the query string and then execute it?

Comment: In the database diagram you provided they are the same datatype, please add all the tables to join to in the diagram so that this is clear. Also explain what output you want from the query (which columns from which tables).